# Passing in double pointer as params in C

Tags: c, struct

Let's say there is an API as follows:

```
void myAPI(int8** ptr)
```

If I want to pass a pointer of a struct into this function this is my code:

```
typedef myStruct {
    int a;
};

myStruct *ptr = NULL;
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(myStruct));

myAPI((int8**)&ptr);
```

My question is what if instead of using `ptr` I now have the following?

```
myStruct myStruct_info;
memset(&myStruct_info, 0, sizeof(myStruct));
```

Would I also be doing `myAPI((int8**)&myStruct_info)`?

Comment: `myStruct *ptr = NULL; memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(myStruct));` invokes undefined behavior since `ptr` doesn't point to any valid memory. In terms of how to correctly call the function, that should be documented. I'd guess the function will allocate space for you, but who knows?

Comment: Shouldn't `int a` be at least `int8 a`?

Comment: `typedef myStruct {
    int a;
};` is not valid C.

Comment: Why isn't `myAPI(int8** ptr)` coded as `myAPI(void ** ptr)` or `myAPI(myStruct** ptr)`?  Knowing that would help provide better answers.  Or at least explain what `myAPI(ptr)` is doing with a `int8** ptr`?

Comment: ... or `myAPI(void *ptr)`.  That the argument is an `int8 **` suggests that the function may be intended to assign a different (pointer) value to `*ptr`, in which case what you describe wanting to do might not make any sense at all.

Comment: The original code will violate the strict aliasing rule if `myAPI` reads or writes through `*ptr`

Comment: Before you could use that API, you would need to read the fine manual to find out what the API does with the `ptr` argument, and why it needs to be a pointer-to-a-pointer. Without that information, you can't sensibly call the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Would I also be doing myAPI((int8**)&myStruct_info)?
```

Short answer is no you can not.

`&myStruct_info` is the address of your `myStruct_info` variable.
And the parameter for your myAPI function needs the address of a pointer to a variable.

If you say `int8 ** a = (int8**)&myStruct_info;` then:

```
a - holds the address of myStruct_info
*a - the value of myStruct_info
```

and

```
**a - means that you take the value stored in myStruct_info and use it as a pointer - REALLY BAD -
```